# systemd drop-ins won't override specific values

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm trying to extend a vendor supplied target/timer to specify which targets should be executed, but eihter way I try, it won't overried the settings.

My first approach was to create a drop-in for the target and change the `Wants` like that:

```
[Unit]
Wants=
Wants=xyz.service
```

My second approch was to create a drop-in for the timer and create a copy of the target with only the needed services. The drop-in looks like that:

```
[Timer]
Unit=copiedAndEdited.target
```

None of these approches worked, although the drop-ins did work. I also changed the description in the same drop-ins and that change has been applied, but not the others. Is it even possible to change those values (`Wants` and `Unit`) or did I do something wrong and if it is not possible, is there a workaround without changing the vendor Unit files?

To be precise whats going on after I made the changes. With the first approche, all the targets still started. With the second approch, the newly created target only starts the specified services, but the timer still starts the original target, not the one from the drop-in.

Im aware of overriding the Units with a copy placed in `/etc/systemd/system/`, but I prefer the drop-ins in case the vendor changes a thing in an version upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to reset dependency lists within the `[Unit]` section (such as `Wants=` or `Requires=`) using a drop-in. You can only append. Use a whole-unit override in order to make other changes.

However, using a drop-in to change `[Timer]` parameters should work without problems. Make sure to call `systemctl daemon-reload`, then the new unit should show up at "Triggers:" in the timer's status text.

Comment: I excpeted this with `Wants`, but in both cases I reloaded the daemon and just now I noticed a warning from `systemctl status xyz.timer` (it was present before). The warning says `Multiple units to trigger specified, ignoring: copiedAndEdited.target`

Comment: Ah, so it is also implemented as a list (for unknown reasons). You need to reset it the same way you tried to reset Wants=.

Comment: Tried that too but then a second warning occurred similar to the first but instead of `copiedAndEdited.target` there only was a blank space. A coworker of mine found the corresponding code segment in `int config_parse_trigger_unit` from https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/load-fragment.c and it seems, that it is not possible to override the `Unit`.